# Why does a fixed lightbox attach itself to the top of the page instead of the top of the viewport?

Tags: html, css

[On this page](http://www.briannaklassen.com/portfolio/), if you scroll down just a bit and then click one of the art pieces, you will see that the "fixed" lightbox is attaching itself to the top of the page rather than the top of the viewport. How do I make it attach to the viewport?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The body had the following CSS styling:

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

When I took this out, the fixed div started behaving properly!